# Cannot get UICollectionView header to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

Here's relevant code:

Controller:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(106.0, 106.0);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0;
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 44.0);

    return (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout]);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // some setup

    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[ITPhotosHeaderView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header"];

}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableView;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        ITPhotosHeaderView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                                          withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        headerView = [[ITPhotosHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 44.0)];
        reusableView = headerView;
    }

    return reusableView;
}
```

Here's the error I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil (<ITPhotosHeaderView: 0x1781b9de0; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x17802f980>>)
```

I debugged and made sure that it wasn't returning nil. Therefore I feel its the `registerClass` part not working correctly. I would appreciate any input. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One definite problem is here:

```
    ITPhotosHeaderView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                                      withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    headerView = [[ITPhotosHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 44.0)];
```

That code is nonsensical. In the first line, you dequeue the header view. In the second line, you wantonly throw away the header view you just dequeued and make a completely new one.

Comment: But I've never seen that particular exception, so it was interesting to learn about! Thus your question was a good one; someone else might stumble on the same exception, after all.